# How should the stack be initialized to in an x86 real mode bootloader to prevent conflicts with BIOS?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, stack-memory, bios

Suppose I want to initialize the stack to a size of `S` bytes.

I would like to chose the base position of the stack `B` so that as the stack grows downward from `B`, I do not end up overwriting any code or other memory being used by the bootloader or the BIOS.

Since I am writing the bootloader myself (and the initial MBR sector is loaded to linear address `0x7c00`), preventing conflicts with the bootloader seems like a matter of careful planning.

**How do I know where the BIOS code is located, and if my stack may be overwriting any memory being used by the BIOS?**

Also, is there any guarantee about where the initial `ss:sp` is pointing, and how much stack space can I safely use without setting a new value?

Comment: The BIOS uses the BIOS data area (BDA) from `0000:0000` to `0000:0500` as well as possibly an extended BIOS data area right at the end of the memory map.  All memory above `0000:0500` indicated by [`int 12h`](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/184-int_12h__conventional_memory_size.html) can be used freely by your code.  When you call a BIOS interrupt, the BIOS may push some data on the stack.  I don't know if there is any documented limit, but about 128 bytes of space should be sufficient.

Comment: Note further that the BIOS itself is located at `F000:0000` to `F000:FFFF` (potentially starting higher up).  It's ROM, so you cannot overwrite it even if you try.  If you don't overwrite the BDA and don't overshoot the limit given by `int 12h`, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Thank you! So setting it anywhere it does not interfere with the BDA is fine.

Comment: Indeed!  And do respect the upper limit of memory given by `int 12h`.  Even if the computer has more conventional memory, any memory above that limit is likely used by the BIOS for various nefarious purposes.

Comment: Ok. Will take care to only use memory below the limit returned by `int 12h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a bootloader will set ss:sp to 00000h:07c00h:. I did a web search, and apparently what ss:sp is set to when the BIOS jumps to the boot loader depends on the BIOS. In the case of Microsoft MBR, the bootloader sets ss:sp to 00000h:07c00h, and transfers most of its code to 00000h:00600h, and jumps to 00000h:006xxh. That in turn looks at the partition table to find a bootable sector and repeats the process, load and jump to 00000h:07c00h. This may repeat one more time. Eventually the boot process will load several sectors and start the actual boot of an Microsoft operating system. I don't know the sequence for Linux type operating systems.